# Rewrite a page name in 2 language

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a web application with 2 languages english and greek, and
I want to make clean urls.

My question is:

For example if one file in my directory is localhost/arxaiologikoi-xwroi.php?lang=gr for greek, and localhost/arxaiologikoi-xwroi.php?lang=en for english,

Is there any possible way to rewrite urls in my .htaccess with mod_rewrite, for example localhost/gr/αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι for greek and localhost/en/archaeological-sites for english

I am sorry if my question is inappropriate and maybe will be down-voted, but i saw so many guides, posts and videos that made really confused.

Thanks in Advance

Vaggelis

Comment: Short answer: yes. Apache doesn't care about the languages, so your [mcve] will be to rewrite `localhost/a/one` to `localhost/one.php?param=a` and `localhost/b/two` to `localhost/one.php?param=b`. Looked at like this, this is about as simple a use of mod_rewrite as you can get. The examples in the Apache manual might be enough to get you started: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: hello @IMSoP and thanks for your answer, i have seen this guide before, and made things more confusing. i tried to rewrite an url with rewriterule: RewriteRule ^/gr/αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι$ arxaiologikoi-xwroi.php?lang=gr [QSA] but when i when i am put this 'localhost/gr/αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι' to url, i get a 404 error. my rewrite engine is on. what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your question - you want to map:

- `/gr/αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι` => `/arxaiologikoi-xwroi.php?lang=gr`
- `/en/archaeological-sites` => `/arxaiologikoi-xwroi.php?lang=en`

As you can see by yourself - this mapping lacks information about relation between your keyword from url and actual script on your server.

Normally such task is solved by so called "front controller" - a script that acts as the single entry point for whole application (and normally it is `index.php`). This script should accept every url, application have and is responsible for deciding what actions should be made.

For example in your case you can have `.htaccess` that will redirect all requests to `index.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and into your `index.php` you will decide what script to call. There can be a lot of approaches, for a sake of example let's pretend that you have mapping defined as a simple array:

```
<?php

$urlMap = [
    'en' => [
        'archaeological-sites' => 'arxaiologikoi-xwroi',
    ],
    'gr' => [
        'αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι' => 'arxaiologikoi-xwroi',
    ],
];

// This will be our default language
$language = 'en';
// This is our default page
$page = 'default';
// Determine if we're handled our request or not
$handled = false;

// I don't want to invent complex routing rules so let's pretend it is simple on of:
// - /page
// - /language/page
$parts = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
$p = array_shift($parts);
if (array_key_exists($p, $urlMap)) {
    // This is language identifier
    $language = $p;
    $p = array_shift($p);
}
if (array_key_exists($p, $urlMap[$language])) {
    // We have special page for handling such request
    $page = $urlMap[$language][$p];
}
// Let's find handler for our page
$path = sprintf(__DIR__ . '/scripts/%s.php', $page);
if (file_exists($path)) {
    // We have handling script, load it
    include_once $path;
} else {
    // We have no handler for request, report "404 Not Found"
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
```

Of course it is very basic example and for real site it is much better to use some (micro-)framework like [Silex](https://silex.symfony.com/), [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) etc.

Comment: hello @Flying and thanks for your answer, i add the proper code in .htaccess and the php in my index and i overright the $language = 'en'; with the $language = $_SESSION['lang']; which can be 'en' or 'gr'. Now i dont get a 404 error but when i try to broswe in /gr/αρχαιολογικοι-χωροι or /en/archaeological-sites i got redirected to my index.php without css and images in greek language. what i am missing?

Comment: You need to have "front controller" code into your `index.php` because `.htaccess` redirects every request to it. Your actual file should reside somewhere else (in `scripts` directory in my example). Missed CSS and images may be caused because of relative urls to them, but I can't tell exactly without seeing whole code layout on your server. You can try to output `$path` variable from my example to see what is being included, maybe it will give you some idea of what goes wrong.

Comment: Ok by saying "front controller" you mean the php code? if yes put it in the top of my index.php. i tried to echo $path and the result is  /Library/WebServer/Documents/scripts/default.php.

Comment: so that means that the $page has the same value from the begining of the script?

Comment: Try to check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is, I wrote this code just as example, it may contain subtle bugs. Also please notice that you may have greek chars urlencoded, in this case `$urlMap` lookup will fail, you'll need to `urldecode()` it first.